# Adding an property with percent value of another property in json object javascript underscore

Tags: javascript, underscore.js

My base data

```
[{
        month: 'Jan',
        cat: 'A',
        val: 20
    },{
        month: 'Jan',
        cat: 'B','
        val: 5
    },{
        month: 'Jan',
        cat: 'C',
        val: 10
    },{
        month: 'Feb',
        cat: 'A',
        val: 30
    },{
        month: 'Feb',
        cat: 'B',
        val: 10
    },{
        month: 'Feb',
        cat: 'C',
        val: 20
    }];
```

I would like to add another property called 'percent' to above object and its value would be the percent of property 'val'

Any help is sincerely appreciated..

Comment: what is the base for the %? or is it the sum of all values?

Comment: 1. That's not [JSON](http://json.org/) but an array of objects, 2. Check your quotes

Comment: @NinaScholz yes, sum of all values

Comment: @Andreas yes its a json object and not a string

Comment: [There's no such thing as a "JSON object"](http://benalman.com/news/2010/03/theres-no-such-thing-as-a-json/)

Comment: @Arnab, Either it is `text` or it is `object`

Comment: @Andreas what is it called.. javascript object or javascript array, in c# we call it jarray

Comment: `input` is an [array `[]`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array) of [objects `{}`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Calculate the total using **[`Array#reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce)** method and then add percentage field using **[`Array#forEach`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach)** method.

```js
var data = [{
  month: 'Jan',
  cat: 'A',
  val: 20
}, {
  month: 'Jan',
  cat: 'B',
  val: 5
}, {
  month: 'Jan',
  cat: 'C',
  val: 10
}, {
  month: 'Feb',
  cat: 'A',
  val: 30
}, {
  month: 'Feb',
  cat: 'B',
  val: 10
}, {
  month: 'Feb',
  cat: 'C',
  val: 20
}];

var total = data.reduce(function(a, b) {
  return a + b.val
}, 0);


data.forEach(function(v) {
  v.percentage = (v.val * 100 / total).toFixed(2)
});

console.log(data);
```